CSS modules not working properly in Next.JS
So the CSS module structure for the project is that you make a module of CSS for each component or page, but this method seems to be problematic. take a look at the code first:
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ffffed;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #eaeaea;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.navbar h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: aqua;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #333;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.navbar a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.icon {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
}


And here is the component:
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from './navbar.module.css';
import { useThemeSelector } from '@/redux/theme/store';
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from '@heroicons/react/16/solid';

export default function Navbar() {
    const isDark = useThemeSelector((state) => state.themeReducer.isDarkMode);
    return (
        <>
            <nav className={styles.navbar}>
                <h1><Link href={'/'}>Home</Link></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link href={'/'}>Create a task</Link></li>
                    {isDark ? <SunIcon className={styles.icon}></SunIcon> : <MoonIcon className={styles.icon}></MoonIcon>}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

Now let me explain what problems I have faced in this single component:

I wanted to make a hover effect for the a tags, and make them to change color, but I found out the color effect does not gets applied at all, neither in the :hover pseudo effect or in the tag itself.
I wanted to make the icon to scroll to the end of the navbar using flexbox and margin-left attribute, but it does not work no matter what, I have found out about a property which is justify-self, that didn't work either.
I have felt that some other functionalities of my styles are not ok, but didn't notice.
My question now are two things, first, how do I fix the problems I have said, and second, is there a bigger problem here ?! Do I have to configure something to use CSS modules ?! I wanna know if I face more problems in the future or not.

I have searched everywhere for any kind of configuration or anything to fix my problem, the documentation of Next.JS itself does not say much, and says it is supported by default, so it seems there is nothing for me to find :/

Add example with jsfiddle or sandbox so we can understand issue and help with it.

@Meet
I will use the things you said and provide the example ASAP

The playgrounds and sandboxes were not the things I wanted, so I pushed the project into the git, you can look at it for yourself.
https://github.com/FrOZEn-FurY/task-management-system

Hey, maybe because you have a:visited with color: inherit after a:hover. I think both have the same specificity so the later will apply because of order of apperance (https://dev.to/receter/avoiding-css-order-of-appearance-problems-with-css-modules-3j7p)

And your icon is outside your <li>

I never used CSS modules but for what I see, I think your problem is not  with the module system but the with the CSS language itself.
You said you want the a elements to change color on hover but on the hover selector you never mention color only text-shadow - which you will barely see because it is set to the same color as all the text in the navbar (incl. a elements). To change the color add color: [color you want];, e.g..
.navbar a:hover {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #333;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  color: red !important; 

 /*edit: add the !important property 
 to make sure the browser 
 prioritizes it (as we discussed in the comments)*/

}

You also mentioned you wanted the icon to be at the end of the navbar and that you tried with flexbox and margin-left properties but you are using the margin-left property wrong: if you want it at the end, you want it at the right side of the browser, so it has to be further away from the left - 1em is too close to the left.
However, you shouldn't even need margins. Just set the justify-content to space-between on the navbar. That way the first item will be 'glued' to the left side of the browser and the last (your icon) to right. And the same for the .navbar ul seletor. Also, always specify the flex-direction. In this case it should be row.
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ffffed;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #eaeaea;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

 (...)

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

I hope this solves your problem :)
If you have any questions just let me know.

You are right and the things you have mentioned is the way to get what I want, but the problem is as I said, they are not working for some reason, to add more details, let me tell you this as well:
I have checked the Chrome developer tools to check if the color style on hover or even not in the hover stats is taking effect, and it was not actually, the funny thing is that it showed me the color inherited from the parent (.navbar) is also replaced with something else, but there was nothing else and the color of the element was exactly the color set into the parent

Another funny fact: !important will make the color property take effect, I mean this syntax to be precise:
color: aqua !important;
but without it, it won't. Also the margin-left is not working no matter what xD

I have also added the things you have mentioned for clarification.

@FrOZEn_FurY that is very weird indeed. I made a quick research about modules and you are doing everything right for what I see, so the problem should not be connection between module and app. Could it be that you have styles being set on the whole app that could be impacting that module? Maybe if you share a jsfiddle we can find the problem more easily.

I have sent the github repo containing the project in the earlier comments, I really don't know, there might be the configurations and the things happening under the hood of Next.JS, but the fact that this simple things are not working made me worried that I might run into more problems later on, but about the fact that you said general styles impacting the component styles, I have set nothing generally actually, just a simple box-sizing property is all.

@FrOZEn_FurY I downloaded your repository and made the changes I mentioned. Everything was working except the color on hover and I don't know why. But by adding !important (as you mentioned) it works. The !important property is exactly for that: if somehow something is interfering with a style you add it there and the browser will know that that is what needs to be displayed. Sometimes we just have to accept that's how the code is working xD. So my advice is: if you encounter a problem like this in the future, try using the !important property.

@FrOZEn_FurY I also updated the code above to included the '!important' in color.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
